# Looking for a simple smoke-test for xvfb

Tags: xvfb

- I have a server (Tomcat) that uses xvfb for headless rendering with libwebkit.
- I have a very short Java sample code to test that the whole setup (xvfb+libwekit, called from Java) works.
- It works on our system (Centos 7.4), but when my customer installs the same (normally) software we get a crash in deep down in libwebkit.

The customer's system are pretty much out of my reach... So I need a simple test that shows that xvfb works fine (without libwebkit) and can be replicated with minimal extra installation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Xvfb with option `-fbdir /dir` you can see the framebuffer in file `/dir/Xvfb_screen0` and you can take a checksum of this at any time to find the same result on any machine of the same architecture. You need to create the directory first. The file is in standard X11 window dump format, so you can also visualise it with `xwud -in /dir/Xvfb_screen0`, though you will need to install `xwd`. If you run `xlogo` or similar and checksum again you should get a new reproducable value. Run `Xvfb` with `-noreset` to avoid it clearing the screen when there a no clients.

You don't need to use `-fbdir`, as you can also take similar screenshots with `xwd -root >outputfile`.